# Find all holomorphic functions given condion:

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions given condition: 
$f(z) = z^{2} \overline{f(z)}$

Sketch: 
$\frac{f(z)^{2}}{z^{2}} = |f(z)|^{2}$

So I have a holomorphic function for $\mathbb{C} -{0}$ that only takes real values.

And I don't have idea about next step.

Comment: Presumably you meant $$\frac{f(z)^2}{z^2} = |f(z)|^2.$$

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Taking a conjugate, you also have that

$$\overline{f(z)} = \overline{z}^2 f(z).$$

Plugging this expression for $\overline{f(z)}$ into the original equation gives

$$f(z) = |z|^4 f(z).$$

Or equivalently

$$f(z)(1-|z|^4) = 0.$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: So $f(z)(1-|z|^{2})(1+|z|^{2}) = 0 \implies $ that |z| = 1 or f(z) = 0 and it's all holomorphic functions

Comment: I have right idea?

Comment: If $|z|=1$, then $f$ can't be holomorphic (holomorphicity requires $f$ to be defined on an open set). If $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$, then how many functions are there..?

Comment: Only one function f(z)=z

Comment: There is only one function, but it certainly isn't $f(z) = z$.. Try plugging $z$ into the original equation and see if it works.